# (R)SAGA: saga_cmd 2.1.0 error? inconsistency?

Tags: r, saga

frequently I am using (R)SAGA, but after SAGA became >2.1.0 the R package is no longer working. The last update for RSAGA was 07/2013. 
Thus I downgraded SAGA to 2.1.0 (first try was skipping the ppa of johanvdw, second try was from source) in order to be able to use RSAGA again. 
Actually this was successful I thought because saga_gui ran well.
Only the more important saga_cmd brings up this:

In bash:

```
[jejune:~]$ saga_cmd
Error: no arguments for saga call
Error: library

62 loaded module libraries (567 modules):
- garden_webservices
- ihacres
```

...

```
- shapes_grid
- table_tools
- ta_compound

    type -h or --help for further information

    Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 762: _dl_close: Assertion `map->l_init_called' failed!
```

In R I can load the package but all functions come up with this error message:

```
    rsaga.get.modules('io_gdal')
    Error: module
    Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 762: _dl_close: Assertion  `map->l_init_called' failed!
    Error in system(command, intern = intern, ...) : error in running command
    >
```

So either there is a workaround to get RSAGA runnning with SAGA >2.1.0 or maybe someone is able to tell me what the error messages mean (and hopefully how to get rid of them)?

system in use:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- R version 3.0.2
- SAGA 2.1.0
- RSAGA 0.93-6

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to be to install the 2.1.2 version:

http://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/bugs/171/ #171 Assertion errors in debian/ubuntu on saga_cmd